# AWS IoT - Cannot locate C SDK to configure device

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

When I click on Onboard option in AWS IoT console, I see an option to register a thing. Clicking on it, followed by Get Started, shows me a page to select an SDK for registration. The first step is to select OS and then a language. At this point, I do not see an option to select a C or a C++ SDK!

The page for [AWS IoT SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html) shows the C/C++ SDK. But, the page for [AWS IoT Device SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-platform/sdk/) does not show the C++ SDK.

1. So, what are these various AWS SDKs? How are they different?
2. What are the differences between a AWS IoT SDK and a [Eclipse Paho](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/) client for connecting to a MQTT broker?
3. What changes maybe needed for an Eclipse Paho client to connect to an AWS IoT MQTT end-point?

My goal is to build MQTT client in C/C++ for a RTOS device. I would register it 'outside' of the device.

Comment: What device are you using?  ESP32 devices, for example, have [their own library](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/aws_iot) that are not provided by Amazon.

Comment: It is a custom device. For now, we are experimenting with a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: The library I pointed to is derived from [this library](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C).  Is this ultimately what you're looking for?

Comment: Possibly. My confusion is with different types of SDK listed on console and documentation. Other question is the inter operability with Eclipse Paho client (that is definitely an option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Different SDKs**

There are 2 main categories of AWS SDKs when it comes to AWS IOT.

- You have the device SDKs that you typically run on a device
- You have the AWS SDKs that you typically run in the cloud

Both come in a variety of languages. Device SDKs typically use MQTT and x509 certificates for authentication to AWS IOT but you can communicate over https as well. [An overview of the supported protocols for iot clients can be found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html). Keep in mind that devices typically tend to use bi-directional long lived communication with aws iot using MQTT (publish / subscribe). The http protocol can only be used to send messages from the device to AWS IOT.

If you're on a C based system you have 2 options :

- CPP : https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp
- Embedded C : https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C

These use standard MQTT communication.

**2. Difference between AWS IoT SDK and Eclipse Paho**

Both will use MQTT / x509 certificates and MQTT_SSL_VERSION_TLS_1_2.
In theory both should work with Aws IOT and I have seen working samples of the Eclispe Paho MQTT client in C++ running against Aws IOT.

From my experience, you're typically better off using the vendors SDK as they will have better support / samples / features then the more generic MQTT libs.

There's also some value about being cloud agnostic and using standard protocols / libraries like MQTT/Paho to avoid (aws) vendor lock-in.

**3. Paho client and AWS IOT**

AWS IoT needs TLS V1.2 so your Paho client needs to support that. I believe it [should be possible now](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/pull/329) with Paho cpp.

Comment: Just curious ... what device SDK should a device use for HTTPS communication? I presume, the AWS SDK can also be run on the device for IoT platform specific functions?

Comment: I would not run the aws sdk (the non-device sdk) on iot devices as you'll leak security credentials (you'll need to connect using aws keys / secrets) and that is not done. You can use https communication with Aws IOT using mutual auth from a C environment without having to use the full AWS SDK.(see updated answer and link on supported protocols)